# How do I remap keyboard shortcuts in UWP C# app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core, uwp

For example, say I wanted to switch `Ctrl`+`C` and `Ctrl`+`V` so that `Ctrl`+`C` will paste and `Ctrl`+`V` will copy. I will need to first override `Ctrl`+`C`copying and then make `Ctrl`+`C` paste. I will have to do the same with `Ctrl` + `V` as well, except I will need to override the paste and make it copy.

How should I go about doing this? Is this possible in a UWP app using C#? Whenever I look up something along the lines of "remapping keyboard shortcuts in c#", it shows me results for remapping keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio, not for in my app.

Answer (score 2):

**>How do I remap keyboard shortcuts in UWP C# app?**

It is a little complicated but you could do it in your app. You need to handle the keyboard input event - [CoreWindow.KeyDown Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corewindow.keydown?view=winrt-19041) first. In the input event, check both if the control key is pressed and if the C key is pressed. When both of them are pressed, then you could do your own logic in the event handler.

Here is a sample code about how to handle the keydown event.

```
  Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;


 private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        var ctrl = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
        if (ctrl.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) && args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.V)
        {
            //clean the data in the clipboard. 
            Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.Clear();
            // do your stuff
            Debug.WriteLine("Ctr+V");
            return;
        } else if(ctrl.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) && args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.C)
        {
            //clean the data in the clipboard. 
            Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.Clear();
            // do your stuff
            Debug.WriteLine("Ctr+C");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Only in your app. UWP apps can't capture system event outside itself.

Comment: Yep, this is the limitation of UWP apps.